# Resizing UITableView ImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do I resize the UIImageView in a UITableViewCell? I'm passing in a large image (at least 100x100px), so the image itself shouldn't be the problem (it should scale down with the imageview)

```
 cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unread.png"];


                CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(25, 25);
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
                CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
                [cell.imageView.image drawInRect:imageRect];
                cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

[image]

Normally the UIImageView in the UITableViewCell is 43 points (or 86 pixels) in height and width. I'd like to size it down to 20 x 20 but this isn't doing anything. Am I missing something?

Comment: Why you are not using custom cell?

Comment: better subclass the UITableViewCell

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the frame of uiimageview of uitableviewcell. You can choose an option from the below

1. Create a custom cell and place a uiimageview at your requirement(which is the best solution and i prefer this one).
2. Use core graphics inside your **cellForRowAtIndexPath:**

   ```
   CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
   CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
   [cell.imageView.image drawInRect:imageRect];
   cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   ```

Comment: thanks for your response. When I try the second method it resizes the imageview, but my image then becomes pixelated. This doesn't really make much sense to me given that I'm scaling down. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I hope following function useful for you:

```
+(UIImage*)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image width:(int)width height:(int)height  {

CGFloat targetWidth = width;
CGFloat targetHeight = height;

CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceInfo = CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef);

if (bitmapInfo == kCGImageAlphaNone) {
    bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;
}

CGContextRef bitmap;

if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp || image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
    bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, targetWidth, targetHeight, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef), colorSpaceInfo, bitmapInfo);

} else {
    bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, targetHeight, targetWidth, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef), colorSpaceInfo, bitmapInfo);

}   


// In the right or left cases, we need to switch scaledWidth and scaledHeight,
// and also the thumbnail point
if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
    CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, radians(90));
    CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, 0, -targetHeight);

} else if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
    CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, radians(-90));
    CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, -targetWidth, 0);

} else if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {
    // NOTHING
} else if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
    CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, targetWidth, targetHeight);
    CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, radians(-180.));
}

CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight), imageRef);
CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
UIImage* newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

CGContextRelease(bitmap);
CGImageRelease(ref);

return newImage; 
}
```